# Twitter integration that supports for IOS4 & IOS 5 and IOS6

Tags: ios, twitter

I am trying to integrate twitter in my universal application which should run on devices with IOS4+. After googling i came to know that for the devices with IOS<4.0 we can use Sharekit and for the devices with IOS>5 we have to use the twitter framework. And that twitter framework should be added weakly (BuildPhases-> beside twitter framework make it optional).

Should i use both of them in my app? If so is there any samples that can be run on devices IOS 4+ devices with the help of either Sharekit or twitter framework. Checking the version of the device and proceeding with the relavant process(either sharekit or twitter framework) is possible? If possible can you help with the snippets or sample.

Answer (score 1):

[DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController) will give you a tweet composer on iOS 4 that looks like the native one in iOS 5/6. In iOS 5+ it will use the native twitter libraries instead.  It's pretty straight forward to setup and use.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. but i am getting 9 errors when i download and run this application in my device like "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and TwitterDialog.h file not found

Comment: Have you definitely followed all of the instructions and included all of the files and needed frameworks?  If all the files are there make sure that they're properly included in 'Build Phases' of your project.